# Sub is exited upon using .Subfolders collection without error MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I am analyzing a file structure , which involves using the .Subfolders collection of the Folder objects. However, once the code gets to the first instance of me using the collection, the sub stops executing code and just quits. No error is shown. Relevant code below:

First, in a different sub, the problematic sub is called:

```
Option Explicit
Public folderlevel As Integer 
Private Sub exportButton_Clicked
Dim fso As Object, startFolder As Object, Path As String, intFileDesc As Integer

'This will summon a file browser window to allow user to navigate comfortably to the folder where the output file should be saved
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 
        .Title = "Please choose the folder where you'd like to save this record"
        .Show
    End With
'Save the selected folder as a string that contains a path (with a backslash at the end for proper syntaxis)
    Path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set startFolder = fso.getFolder(Path)
    intFileDesc = FreeFile
    folderLevel = 0
    getContents startFolder, intFileDesc

    Debug.Print "Output Finished"
End Sub
```

And then the code of the actual sub :

```
    Sub getContents(ByRef prntfldr As Object, targetFile As Integer)
    Dim SubFolder As Object, File As Object, SFCollection
    
    folderLevel = folderLevel + 1
    Debug.Print "getContents entered, starting analysis from  " & prntfldr.Name
    Set SFCollection = prntfldr.Subfolders
    Debug.Print "Entering first subfolder"
    
    For Each SFolder In SFCollection
         Print #targetFile, "|"; String((50 * (folderLevel - 1)) - 1, " "); "|"; String(49, "-"); SFolder.Name
         Debug.Print "Level " & folderLevel & ", Working in folder " & SFolder.prntfldr.Name & ", printing contents of" & SFolder.Name
         getContents SFolder, targetFile
    Next SFolder
    folderLevel = folderLevel - 1
End Sub
```

Added the "Set" to SFCollection line, which gets me to the For Each loop, but nothing gets printed to the file nor immediate window.

The weirdest part is that this code worked perfectly fine in Excel.

Comment: Where is intFileDesc set? I get error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" on the SFCollection line. Code provided seems to be incomplete, at least not complete enough to allow testing. Some variables used are not declared.

Comment: As @June7 said.  Also `intFileDesc` is passed to `getContents` as an integer (`targetFile`), but isn't used anywhere that I can see.

Comment: @june7 edited the question with a little fix (Added a "Set" to the SFCollection line, which should fix the error you got (but I wonder why I never got it)) and full context (with declarations and other). Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook added the lines where targetFile is used

Comment: For debugging, I suggest to set a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and use early binding. `Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject`, `Dim oFolder As Scripting.Folder` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This modification doesn't error and has output to immediate window:

```
    For Each SubFolder In SFCollection
         Debug.Print "Level " & folderlevel & ", Working in folder " & _
                     prntfldr.Name & ", printing contents of " & SubFolder.Name
         getContents SubFolder, targetFile
    Next SubFolder
```

Might find this of interest http://allenbrowne.com/ser-59.html